How to use gpu 1 instead of gpu 0 in tensorflow?
I installed TensorFlow and my laptop has 2 GPUs, GPU 0 (integrated graphics) and GPU 1 (dedicated graphics). When I want to use TensorFlow, my available GPU is one and is GPU 0
How can I change GPU 0 to GPU 0?
My physical device is only GPU 0 and there is no GPU 0

I believe your question contains some typos that blurs the meaning of it. Please write it in clear way, and provide more details on your problem.

This question is similar to: How to set specific gpu in tensorflow?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You can find all available GPUs in tensorflow with: GPUs = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU') if the other GPU doesn't show up maybe check the driver of the GPU
